# jQuery - how can I find if an id has a specific string?

Tags: jquery

I have a table and I want to know if its last td its id contains a certain string.
For example, if my last td has id "1234abc", I want to know if this id contains "34a".
And I need to do that in a 'if' statement.

if(myLastTdId Contains "blablabla"){ do something }

Thanks!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5866314/900284

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use the "[attributeContains](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeContains)" selector:

```
if($("#yourTable td:last-child[id*='34a']").length > 0) { 
   //Exists, do something...
}
```

Comment: And, if your "something" consists of a jQuery operation, say setting a css, you can just chain it up -- no if required: ("#yourTable td:last-child[id*='34a']").css("color", "red");

Comment: ^ insert $ at beginning of expression

Comment: The `> 0` portion is redundant. Just `element.length` will work.

Answer (score 12):

This is easily done with `indexOf` and `last-child`.

```
<table id='mytable'>
<tr>
  <td id='abc'></td>
  <td id='cde'></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
if($('#mytable td:last-child').attr('id').indexOf('d') != -1) {
   alert('found!');
}
</script>
```

Here it would alert 'found' because `d` appears in the string `cde`

Answer (score 2):

If your `td` is "bare" (i.e. not wrapped in a jQuery object), you can access its `id` attribute directly:

```
if (myTD.id.indexOf("34a") > -1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

If it *is* in a jQuery object, you'll need to get it out first:

```
if (jMyTD[0].id.indexOf("34a") > -1 {
    // do stuff
}
```

The `indexOf` function finds the offset of one string within another.  It returns -1 if the first string doesn't contain the second at all.

**Edit:**

On second thought, you may need to clarify your question.  It isn't clear which of these you're trying to match "34a" against:

- `<td id="1234abcd">blahblah</td>`
- `<td id="blahblah">1234abcd</td>`
- `<table id="1234abcd"><tr><td>blahblah</td></tr></table>`
- `<table id="blahblah"><tr><td>1234abcd</td></tr></table>`

Answer (score 2):

Not completely clear if you mean last td in each tr, or the very last td:

```
if ($('#myTable td:last[id*=34a]').length) {
    ...
}
```