# Get all div values of similiar id in a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div structure like below

```
    <div id=main">
<input type="hidden" id="people_0_1_0" value="12"/>
<input type="hidden" id="people_0_1_1" value="12"/>
</div>
```

Now how to add all hidden input values in a variable. Thanks

Comment: "In a variable"? Can you show an example result, please?

Comment: this is the only example

Comment: Using any client side? Do you have your that code?

Comment: You need to provide more details as to what you want to achieve.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - how can I find if an id has a specific string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640903/jquery-how-can-i-find-if-an-id-has-a-specific-string)

Comment: Do you want a varaible that contains "1212" which is the result of all hidden fields?

Answer (score 5):

Using Jquery's `map` function

```
var myArray = $('#main input').map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

It will collect all input's values(12 and 12 in this case) to array variable.

See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GkXUS/1/

If you want to get sum of values you can do the following

```
var total = 0;
$.each(myArray,function() {
    total += parseInt(this,10);
});
​
```

Comment: Quick question about map, what are the benefits of using it over just a selector and an each (in this example)? (obviously less code but is it quicker as well?)

Comment: @Magrangs `map` gives you the collection as a result value, whereas with an `each` you would have to init the collection outside the each-callback and add to it while iterating through the elements.

Comment: Adding Yoshi's comment, map is returning new array, each is returning same array. So in this case needed to make new array, so it says you about using map. Less code is one another benefit.
See this for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749084/jquery-map-vs-each

Comment: @Chuck - Why would you use `map` and then run each loop on the array to get the sum if it can be achieved with just one loop?

Comment: No need. I just show the way to count the sum. He can do at without map.

Answer (score 3):

```
var total = 0;

$('#main input[id^="people_"]').each(function(){
     total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
});
```

Note that I am using attribute starts with selector to find all the input elements whose id starts with `people_`.

`total` will give you the total of all the input elements value.

Comment: +1: This is the only answer that addresses all the requirements.

Comment: One suggestion - I would edit the answer and add the `#main` div to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this:

```
var hidden_value = new Array();
var hiddens = document.getElementById( "main" ).childNodes;
for( i = 0 ; i < hiddens.length ; i++ ){
    hidden_value.push( hiddens[ i ].value );
}
```

Comment: Your code will not work, this is your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sK4Nt/ , check my answer.

Comment: @SheikhHeera that's the answer: [undefined, "12", undefined, "12", undefined]. Now, the "12"-s stand for the answer. Not arguing about editing the code +)

Comment: OP wants only values from hidden inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var peopleData = $("#main input[type=hidden]").serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting values in a variable does not make sense. You can insert the values in a Array and perform your required operation

Comment: You can't add numbers and put the sum in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Using Plain Javascript

```
var els=document.getElementById('main').childNodes;
var a​llVal​=​​​​​​​​[];
for(i=0; i<els.length-1; i++)
{
    if(els[i].nodeType != 3 && els[i].type=="hidden") allVal.push(els[i].value); 
}
console.log(allVal); // the array
console.log(allVal[0]); // first value
```

An example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4YJPZ/).