# jQuery endsWith for attributes

Tags: jquery

using jQuery, I'm trying to see if a random id ends with a certain string using the following pseudo code:

```
var node = $('#foobar');

if (node.attr('id').endsWith('bar')) {
 // do stuff
}
```

I know for node selection you can go `$(id?='bar')` , but I need something that works for `$.attr()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Selector: Id Ends With?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609382/jquery-selector-id-ends-with)

Comment: different problem. the suggested duplicate is trying to select an element. i'm trying to take some jQuery object and test to see if the attr('id') ends with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the desired object and therefore also have the id string as in your example, then this is just a question about matching something at the end of a string so you could just match the id string vs. a regular expression:

```
if (node.attr('id').search(/bar$/) != -1) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (node.filter("[id$='bar']").length > 0){
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="foo-bar">asd</div>

if ($("div[id$='bar']")) {
 // do stuff
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PsaHQ/1/

Comment: If you aleady know that id is `foobar` again you are looking for id endswith `bar`, what is the use of this?

Comment: this is for selecting an element, not for testing to see if an elements attr ends with 'bar'

Comment: @tester is right. The right use case for this is when we have a set of elements and we want to filter them whose id ends with `bar` string.

Comment: @tester - Take a look at my answer that will help you.