# How can I bind a click event using wildcard jquery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Selector: Id Ends With?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609382/jquery-selector-id-ends-with)

Suppose I have controls called **ctl00_mstPartBase_lblTopPager** and 
**ctl00_mstPartBase_lblBottomPager**.

These controls have many hyperlinks. I want to bind a click event for those hyperlinks. I have tried:

```
$('#lblTopPager #lblBottomPager a').click(function (e) {
        alert("click occured");
        e.preventDefault();

});
```

However the above code does not work because my control name is  **ctl00_mstPartBase_lblTopPager**

How could I bind a click event with those hyperlinks when the parent control's name is not fixed, the only fixed parts are `lblTopPager` and `lblBottomPager`.

What code should I write such that a single click binding will work for all the hyperlinks in the two containers. Please help. Thanks

### I did it in this way

```
    $('[id$=lblTopPager] a, [id$=lblBottomPager] a').live("click", function (e) {
        alert($(this).text() + ' this is my anchor text ');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id*=btnOk]').live("click", function () {

});

});

Comment: Have you tried binding the event to a class as opposed to the id?

Comment: this are lblTopPager html tag. lblTopPager  is span basically. i want to access it by id.....is it possible.

Answer (score 3):

This should select all the elements with id ending in **lblTopPager**

```
$("[id$=lblTopPager]")
```

and this should select all the `a` elements which parents id ends in **lblTopPager**

```
$("[id$=lblTopPager] a")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/jquery-select-a-which-href-contains-some-string