# Moved inline javascript to external file

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

$('#<%=pnlCheckout.ClientID%> div.listitem').length am having this on my page level javascript I have to move this to external javascript file could anyone plz help me how to do this ?

Comment: what????????????? you just want a single statement on a new js file

Comment: No actually I moved everything and I have some asp code in btwn this javascript which i have to convert either into java script or jquery as we cannot use asp coding in external java script file

Comment: You would probably add the server data to a data attribute of an element, and retrieve this data using javascript.

Comment: What are you asking, what is this question?

Comment: Please improve the question with more information

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `nameOfFile.js` and copy your javascript code to it, without the `<script>` tags that surrounded it inline.  Then load the external file into your main file using the `<script>` src attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pathToFile.js"></script>
```

Comment: won't work, as the OP's using .NET databinding on the page within the js selector.

Comment: Really..??I did all these I moved all the java script into external js file.. I have some asp code in btwn this javascript which i have to convert either into java script or jquery.so am facing prob with this particular line..as that is asp code i have to convert that into javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery [`ends with`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector here:

```
$('[id$="pnlCheckout"]')
```

Which will match any element for which the ID ends with `pnlCheckout`

Your final js would then be:

```
 $('[id$="pnlCheckout"] div.listitem').length
```

related: [jQuery Selector: Id Ends With?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609382/jquery-selector-id-ends-with)