# jquery selection for starting with something and ending with something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select the elements with id which starts with 'start-' and ends with 'end-' string. How to get this done using jquery selector? One line selector please?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609382/jquery-selector-id-ends-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that answer would select two types both thoose who end- without having start and the other way around the right answer would be this one

http://jsfiddle.net/XQBGs/

```
$('[id|="start"][id$="end-"]')
```