# asp.net, validate as user is writing on textbox

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on ASP.NET with C#.

I have a `TextBox` and I want to validate if the user is writing the correct length for the `TextBox`.

If the user is not entering the correct length I want a message to display on a label. But I want this check to happen on the fly, as the user is writing.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose these are your asp.net elements

```
<asp:label id="message" runat="server"/><br/>
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="txtTest"/>
```

your js should be something like:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[id$='txtTest']").bind('keypress', function(){   
        if($("input[id$='txtTest']").val().length < 10)
            $("[id$='message']").text('incorrect length');
       else
        $("[id$='message']").text('');
    });
});
```

note that `id$='message` and `input[id$='txtTest']` in jQuery means [id ends with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609382/jquery-selector-id-ends-with)

When you mark an element to be run at server, asp.net append some other names at the start of the actual client id based on the name of you page.

and here is [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NrBNy/)

Comment: Thanks. Its working.......But if I write the desired length on the textbox, and then erase characters with backspace button on keyboard so it would go under the desired length, the message does not show up again...How can I modify it so it can detect when the backspace button is deleting characters?

Comment: On the working demo you posted the backspace button works, but when I test it on my machine it doesn't.

Comment: @pyram, could you post your code, and I'll see what's the discrepancy then.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery for it. Have a div next to your textbox, hook up an onchange() event for your textbox, and just have jQuery populate the div with your message if the length of the textbox's val() is not long enough.

```
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" onchange="changeMessage" />
<div id="message"></div>

<script>
function changeMessage(){

  var textboxLength = $('#myTextBox').val().length;
  if(textboxLength < ...){
    $('#message').html('Your Message');
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is not working... I see you are declaring an <input type="text". But im using an asp textbox: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" .......Do I need to change something so it can work?

Comment: in the jQuery change $('#myTextBox') to $("#<%= yourTextBoxesID.ClientID %>") - this will get the id of the textbox and go from there