# get ids end with any string from given array of strings

Tags: jquery

i found a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/609382/1564818) to get the id's which are ending with a specific string.

```
  $("element[id$='txtTitle']")
```

How can we get the id's if ending strings are many. Like i have an array of strings and want all id's that are ending with anyone of these strings.

Thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine selector with different `endings` with comma.

```
$("element[id$='txtTitle1'],  element[id$='txtTitle2'])")
```

When you have different ending and same `start` use start.

```
$("element[id^='txtTitle']")
```

When you have some text `common` but not sure if it is in start or end or middle use `*`

```
 $("element[id*='txtTitle']")
```

Comment: Not the case all have different starts ,

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can combine multiple selectors.

Comment: i have an array dynamically generated, thou i can make this selector string first in a loop and than can use, but hopefully there must be a good solution.??

Comment: @mansoor if you want to create the selector via your array check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of strings containing the ending of the `id` you can loop over them and add them to a collection. Try this:

```
var $elements = $(); // empty jQuery object
var ids = ["txtTitle", "txtFirstname", "txtLastName"];
$.each(ids, function(index, value) {
    $elements.add("element[id$='" + value + "']");
});

// $elements is now a collection you can use eg:
$elements.css("background-color", "#C00");
```

Answer (score 0):

Build up the selector first:

```
var endings = ["a","b","c"];
var selector = "";

for(var i = 0, len = endings.length; i < len; i++) {
   selector += "element[id$='" + endings[i] + "']";

   if (i != (endings.length - 1)) selector += ",";
}
```

Then do the selection:

```
var el = $(selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have an array of endings

```
var arr = ["ending1","ending2"];
```

You can use the jquery [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function to build up a multiple selector (separated by a comma)

```
var selector = $.map(arr,function(i,e){return "element[id$='" + e + "']";})
                .join(",");
// result: "element[id$='ending1'],element[id$='ending2']"
```

Then use the selector:

```
var $elements = $(selector);
```