# How do I delete all div with an id that begins with xyz with dojo 1.8.3?

Tags: dojo, destroy

I want to delete all `<div>` which id begins with xyz from the dom tree.

I know that this can be done with dojo.query and dojo.destroy but I never used this combination before.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var divNodesWidgets = dijit.findWidgets('[id^="divNodes"]');
dojo.forEach(divNodesWidgets, function(d) {
    d.destroyRecursive(true);
});

var UlWidgets = dijit.findWidgets('[id^="ulNodes"]');
dojo.forEach(UlWidgets, function(u) {
u.destroyRecursive(true);
});

var headingWidgets = dijit.findWidgets('[id^="h1Nodes"]');
dojo.forEach(headingWidgets, function(h) {
h.destroyRecursive(true);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609382/jquery-selector-id-ends-with

Check this may Help you for you question

Answer (score 2):

Is what you are destroying a widget or just an Element, if its just an element try with:

```
    dojo.forEach(dojo.query('[id^="xyz"]'), function(entry,idx){
     dojo.destroy(entry);
    alert(entry + " Destroyed");
});
```

or

```
dojo.query('[id^="xyz"]').forEach(dojo.destroy);
```

Comment: the answer comes late, sorry. i want to destroy widgets. i edited my post above with some code

Comment: What ive used in the past that seems to work is a combo of. entry.destroyDescendants() and entry.destroy().

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Jquery Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Please go through this and you will get to know what you have to do

Answer (score 0):

I just add this answer for the sake of using AMD syntax, since you are using dojo 1.8.3, otherwise I would go for tik27's second proposal.

```
require(["dojo/query", 
         "dojo/dom-construct", 
         "dojo/domReady!"
], function(query, domConstruct){
    query("div[id^='xyz']").forEach(domConstruct.destroy);
});
```

See http://dojo-sandbox.net/psoares/2a702/1