# Id ends with any of the given texts

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609382/jquery-selector-id-ends-with) thread we can use the syntax `$("element[id$='txtTitle']")` to select all the elements whose ids end with 'txtTitle'. How can we use multiple ids with this syntax.?

1. It means how can we select all the elements ends with either with 'txtTitle' or 'txtName'?
2. I am using this selector with JSF2s `render` attribute. For a single Id, I'm using it as `render="@([id$=txtTitle])"`. How can I use `render` attribute when using multiple ids with above syntax?

Comment: $("element[id$='txtTitle'], element[id$='txtName']")

Comment: You probably can't use jQuery syntax in JSF's `render`. jQuery works in the browser after the page is displayed, JSF's AJAX stuff needs to be set up as the component tree is built on the server side.

Comment: You can use jQuery selectors only in primefaces (`update` and `process`) http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you very much. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Daniel and millimoose Thanks for the tip. I really hadn't noticed that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access more than one set if you separate with commas

```
var sets =$("element[id$='txtTitle'], element[id$='txtName']");
```