# how to get part of textbox id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have one textbox .the id is account_0__abc.the id will dynamically generted one.my question is how to select the id ending with  __abc textboxes in a whole form using jquery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609382/jquery-selector-id-ends-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various selectors in jQuery to identify elements based on a part of their id or names. You can specify the element type as well.

Here's an example:

```
$('input[id$="__abc"]')
```

This will grab `<input>` elements with id ending with `__abc`. Be careful though, if you got multiple ones that match this criteria, you'll end up with a collection. You can iterate through the collection and do stuff to them with a `.each()` like so:

```
$('input[id$="__abc"]').each(function(){
    // magic
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use [**`attribute ends with selector`**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/),

```
$('[id$="__abc"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it more specific such as start with `account_` and end with `__abc` then you can use:

```
$('[id^="account_"][id$="__abc"]')
```

- https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/