# Getting value of an input text (telerik:RadTextBox) by jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, textbox, jquery-selectors, telerik

I have this control in my page:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtTitleMyLink" Runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
```

This is how it looks when it's rendered:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$popupAddMyLink$C$txtTitleMyLink" class="riTextBox riEnabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_popupAddMyLink_C_txtTitleMyLink" value="">
```

**I want to get what user types after the page is loaded.** I call the line below from a button. It works but I don't want to use it since it could be change based on the containers:

```
$("#ctl00_MainContent_popupAddMyLink_C_txtTitleMyLink").val();
```

How can I accomplish getting the value based on a string? 
These ones are not working:

```
$("[id*=txtTitleMyLink]").val();
$("[id*='txtTitleMyLink']").val();
$("[id*='txtTitleMyLink']").text();
$("[id*='txtTitleMyLink']").attr('value');
$('#txtTitleMyLink').val();
$('#txtTitleMyLink').text();
```

Comment: try **$('#txtTitleMyLink').val();** or try **$('#txtTitleMyLink').text();**. Since the telerik control (apparently) is altering the ID of your element, you may have to try and alter the jquerys selector using *ctl00_MainContent_popupAddMyLink_C_txtTitleMyLink*

Comment: @jbutler483 `$('#txtTitleMyLink').val();` or `$('#txtTitleMyLink').text();` are not working. I edited my post

Comment: what about replacing that selector with the longer id?

Comment: @jbutler483 It works as I mentioned in my question. However, I don't want to use the exact ID because it will change if somebody changes the name of the control `popupAddMyLink`

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/609399/3436942)

Comment: It works. I don't why asterisk (*) doesn't work but dollar sigh ($) works. Anyways, I'll select it if you post it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the * (commonly used as 'all' in css), is slightly different in jquery. So, by using the $ (known as 'Jquery') will do as you want.

> If you know the element type then: (eg: replace 'element' with 'div')

```
$("element[id$='txtTitle']")
```

> If you don't know the element type:

```
$("[id$='txtTitle']")
```

So, in your case, you would look to use:

```
$("[id$=txtTitleMyLink]")
```

to select your id '*which contains the words txtTitleMyLink*' into your jquery select statement.