# Select all elements in TD with certain ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I select all elements in my `td` whose id ends with a `2`?

In my code, the `IDs` of the 2nd and 4th element end with a `2`, so those elements background color should turn red.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="abc|1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="def|2">
        <option>123</option>
        <option>456</option>
        <option>789</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="ghi|1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="jkl|2">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is my approach:

```
$("table td:nth-child(1)[id$=2]").css("background-color", "red");
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/torjpv9t/2/).

Comment: They aren't id... they are class name

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf: My bad. I've corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this jQuery

```
$("table td:nth-child(1) [id$=2]").css("background-color", "red");
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/torjpv9t/3/

Note : You can simply use `$("[id$=2]")` as selector.

Comment: What is important to note here is the space between the `td:nth-child(1)` and `[id$=2]`. This is because the element with id ending in 2 is a descendant and separate from the `td`

Answer (score 2):

First issue is that your FIDDLE doesn't work because you've forgotten to include jQuery.

The second issue is your query. Spacing is important when defining selectors. In your query, you have `td:nth-child(1)[id$=2]`. Because there is no space between `td:nth-child(1)` and `[id$=2]`, you're basically looking for a `td` with a particular id. What you want is to find the input element *within* the `td`. This would be more appropriate `td:nth-child(1) [id$=2]` - notice the space between. The space indicates that you want to search *all decendants* of the `td`. If you wanted to search only direct children, you could use the `>` to denote that like this `td:nth-child(1) > [id$=2]`.

You can simplify your query as well for this particular scenario. If you want all inputs that have an ID that ends in `2`, then you can use jquery `:input` pseudo-selector to target them like so:

`$(":input[id$=2]").css("background-color", "red");`

https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

> Description: Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

Answer (score -1):

[jQuery Selector: Id Ends With?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609382/jquery-selector-id-ends-with)

http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

Just take a look at this links..

If you know the element type then: (eg: replace 'element' with 'div')

```
 $("element[id$='txtTitle']")
```

or

use asterisk '*' at the beginning

```
   $('*[id*=mytext]:...
```

like this